# invert screen permanently in arch linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, xorg, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card

I am currently in a fresh install of Arch Linux (Antergos). i have installed nvidia drivers and bumblebee i have already created a xorg.conf using sudo nvidia-xconfig and saved the settings using sudo nvidia-settings however when i reboot the system does not invert here is the xorg file text.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.38  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-15)  Wed Jan  8 19:53:03 PST 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "QDS"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400M GS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1280x800_60 +0+0 {rotation=invert}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=invert, viewportout=1280x720+0+40}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=invert, viewportin=1024x768, viewportout=1066x800+107+0}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=invert, viewportin=800x600, viewportout=1066x800+107+0}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=invert, viewportin=640x480, viewportout=1066x800+107+0}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the screen will not stay inverted after a reboot of the system every time i log in i have to manually invert the screen again.

Answer (score 0):

(Probably a dead post but hey- ) Place the line that you use to invert the screen (probably `xrandr --output $output_name --rotate inverted` in one of the files that gets sourced at x startup, what file that is depends on your setup (what window manager and display manager you are using). For most cases this file tends to be [~/.xprofile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile).